# Linear equation with two unknowns

Tags: systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations, functional-equations

Why the indeterminate equation, which has coprime coefficients, gives the same solution when we set the value of one variable to equal the value of the other variable?
I will clear it with an example:
For instance, we have 
$$43x+47y=450$$
Now we put $x=y$.

Then $$43x+47x=450$$
  Or, $$90x=450$$
 Or $x=5$ 
 Hence $x=y=5$ is *a* solution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What about $2x+3y=1$?

Comment: I don't think this always works when we are only looking at integer solutions. I can come up with many examples where it doesn't produce integer solutions ...

Comment: What is interesting about this equation is: $$45(y+x)+2(y-x)=450\\2(y-x)=45(10-y-x),$$ but it doesn't mean anything.